# SQL- how do i fix my code(given below) so that it works with subqueries?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: table]
so the question is "how many employees work in Mumbai?", I's would generally write my code as follows

```
select loc, count(*) from dept where loc = 'Mumbai' GROUP BY loc;
```

But here it's a subquery, how do I fix my code?

Comment: I don't see a subquery...

Comment: I meant fetching data from two tables, how do I fix this code.

Answer (score 1):

Really basic way if your class hasn't covered joins yet:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM emp
WHERE deptno = (
  SELECT deptno
  FROM dept
  WHERE loc = 'Mumbai'
);
```

If your class has covered joins, think of what a join looks like:

```
SELECT emp.*, dept.*
FROM emp
JOIN dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno
ORDER BY emp.eno;
```

Run that query and take a look at the results. You'll have the five employee rows and each row will have the employee's department information.

You can count on the joined tables. It's like running the count against the results of query above:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM emp
JOIN dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno
WHERE dept.loc = 'Mumbai';
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables by the deptno and add where dept.loc = 'Mumbai'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 select count(*) from dept where loc =(select loc from dept where loc ='mumbai')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Perhaps add a bit of context, explaining your answer, and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perform join on `deptno`, filter by the location you want and sum the number of records:

```
select sum(1) from dept, emp where dept.deptno = emp.deptno and dept.loc = 'mumbai';
```

Answer (score 0):

select count(*) from emp123 e inner join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno where loc =(select loc from dept where loc ='mumbai')